# Variadic function template strange error message for unresolved overloaded argument

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I came across a confusing error when accidentally passing an overloaded function to a variadic function template:

```
template<typename... Args>
void variadic(Args... args) {}

void overloaded() {}
void overloaded(int) {}

int main()
{
    variadic(overloaded);
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:24: error: too many arguments to function 'void variadic(Args ...) [with Args = {}]'
     variadic(overloaded);
                    ^
prog.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
 void variadic(Args... args) {}
      ^
```

If I replace the variadic function template with a normal function template I get a clearer error message:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:25: error: no matching function for call to 'templated(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     templated(overloaded);
                         ^
prog.cpp:2:6: note: candidate: template<class Arg> void templated(Arg)  void templated(Arg args) {}
      ^
prog.cpp:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:9:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Arg'
     templated(overloaded);
                         ^
```

Can anyone explain why the variadic error message is different? I know why there is one, just not why it's different from the normal template error.

I'm using g++ 5.2.1 with C++14.

Try it here: https://ideone.com/8XZexs

Comment: Your code is ambiguous, how should the compiler decide which `overloaded`  function is passed to the `variadic` function.

Comment: @t.niese I know it is. I'm just trying to understand why the two error messages (variadic vs non-variadic) are different

Comment: Visual studio is complaining that `error C2660: 'variadic': function does not take 1 arguments`

Comment: clang tells you for the variadic version that  `Candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided`, I would assume the because it is ambiguous, that no version of the `variadic` function taking one argument is created, as of that you get the message that you pass a wrong argument count.  For the template version the argument count is fixed, so the more specific test for the type is done which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the question of *why* the error message is the way it is isn't the interesting question - there's no standard that governs what the error messages contain. The important point is that gcc (and clang) correctly rejects the code as ill-formed and are able to point to the offending line.

The error in question from gcc:

```
main.cpp:9:24: error: too many arguments to function 'void variadic(Args ...) [with Args = {}]'
     variadic(overloaded);
                    ^
```

and clang:

```
main.cpp:9:5: error: no matching function for call to 'variadic'
    variadic(overloaded);
    ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
void variadic(Args... args) {}
     ^
```

happen to be pretty misleading. It seems as if having failed to deduce an `Args...` for `overloaded` (since that deduction is not possible), both compilers fallback to trying to instantiate an empty parameter pack for `Args...` and only report the non-viability of `void variadic() { }` as an overload for `variadic(overloaded)`. In the non-variadic case, there is no such fallback and both compiler errors are much more useful.

It's a poor error message and hopefully some future compiler versions will improve upon it - but the important thing is to understand *why* the code is ill-formed (as you seem to), not what the specific error message happens to be.

Comment: That explanation makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you want to pass pointer to a function into you `variadic` function?

If that is really what you want to do then you need to specify explicitly pointer to which function you want to pass. For example (selects `overloaded(int)`):

```
void (*fn)(int) = overloaded;
variadic(fn);
```

or (selects `overloaded()`)

```
void (*fn)() = overloaded;
variadic(fn);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. I want to know why the error messages are different, not why they exist.